# How to get the time in hours minutes in python

Tags: python

I want to split the date and time and need to add hours minutes in time

How to convert that in python can any one help me

My code is

```
Date = "7days,15:18:21.727067"
Print(str(Date).split(".")[0])
```

Output is

```
7days,15:18:21
```

I want output to be

```
7days 15hours 21 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

This cheapest way to achieve this is:

```
Date = "7days,15:18:21.727067"

my_split_date = str(Date).split(".")[0]
my_split_date_again_split = my_split_date.split(',')
my_split_date_again_split_second = my_split_date_again_split[1].split(':')

final_output = my_split_date_again_split[0] + ' ' + my_split_date_again_split_second[0] + ' Hours ' + my_split_date_again_split_second[1] + ' Minutes'
    
print(final_output)
```

Output

```
7days 15 Hours 18 Minutes
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the hour and minute, you can use the datetime and strftime function from the datetime module

```
from datetime import datetime

hour = datetime.today().strftime("%H")
min = datetime.today().strftime("%M")
```

---

---

Comment: That is a general answer for the _current_ date/time_, but  the OP was trying to find that information from a specifically formatted string.

Comment: @Erwin Ok. Maybe I misinterpreted the question. Will keep that in mind next time. Thanks for pointing that out!